# Storing an std::vector in shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, vector, shared-memory, mmap

I'm trying to share an `std::vector` between two processes by storing it in shared memory. The first process tries to add some data to the vector and the second process tries to read the data.

To create the vector I use something like this:

```
offset_t offset = custom_malloc(sizeof(std::vector<char, CustomAllocator<char>>));

uint8_t *ptr = shared_memory_base_ptr + offset;

std::vector<char, CustomAllocator<char>> *shared_vector = new (ptr) std::vector<char, CustomAllocator<char>>();
shared_vector->push_back('S');
shared_vector->push_back('h');
shared_vector->push_back('a');
```

To read the vector from the second process I use the following:

```
const uint8_t *ptr = shared_memory_base_ptr + offset;

const std::vector<char, CustomAllocator<char>> *shared_vector = reinterpret_cast<const std::vector<char, CustomAllocator<char>> *>(ptr);
std::cout << shared_vector->size() << std::endl;  // 3
std::cout << shared_vector->at(0) << std::endl;  // Segfault
```

The problem is that when trying to access any vector position using `vector->at(i)`, I get a segmentation fault due to invalid memory address.

I've tried printing the address of the element in the vector using `&(vector->at(i))` and it looks like it's the virtual address that corresponds to the first process that created the vector which will probably be an invalid address for the second process.

Is there any way this can be overcome? How can the second process know the correct addresses for the vector elements?

EDIT: For completeness, I'm also providing sample code for the custom allocator that I'm using for the vector:

```
template <typename T>
class CustomAllocator
{
public:
    using value_type = T;

    CustomAllocator() noexcept {}

    T *allocate(std::size_t n) {
        const offset_t offset = custom_malloc(n * sizeof(T));
        return reinterpret_cast<T *>(shared_memory_base_ptr + offset);
    }

    void deallocate(void *p, std::size_t n) {
        (void)n;
        if (p) {
            const offset_t offset = static_cast<uint8_t *>(p) - shared_memory_base_ptr);
            custom_free(offset);
        }
    }
};
```

I understand that the vector itself holds pointers to its underlying structures which will not be valid in a separate process, unless the shared memory is mapped at the same virtual address as pointed by @Dmitry in the comments.

Comment: Can you share memory successfully with your custom allocator?

Comment: You can map the same virtual address space into two different processes (`mmap` first argument is desirable start address, and use `MAP_FIXED_NOREPLACE` flag). It is the easiest way in my experience.  Assuming of course everything else is correct.

Comment: You cannot reliably share data structures that contain pointers. You *might* be able to mmap at the same address but there is no guarantee that the same address range is free in all processes at the same time. Boost comes with utilities for [shared vector-like objects](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/interprocess/quick_guide.html#interprocess.quick_guide.qg_interprocess_container), instead.

Comment: "The first process tries to add some data to the vector and the second process tries to read the data." Could you use a pipe instead?

Comment: In addition to all the other concerns mentioned, you'll need to add interprocess synchronization. Otherwise you have a race condition. For example if one process `clear()`'s the vector, who knows what state the vector will be in if the other process inspects it at that moment. Without it, the compiler might also see that the vector can't actually change and optimize locally, ignoring that its memory representation could be changed externally. After all, `x->size() == x->size();` can be assumed to be true (normally). It might not be indented to be true in your case.

Comment: Could you share your `CustomAllocator` implementation? It seems like the issue might be there.

Comment: Could you now also provide the implementation of `custom_malloc`, so we can compile the code. This is necessary to find a solution. But it is already evident that your solution cannot work as is. You need a custom pointer type that is exposed in your allocator class, that handles _offset_ to _actual pointer_ conversion.

Answer (score -1):

`vector` is more than just the data it holds, it's also a pointer that points to the heap-allocated memory where the data is stored. So while you put the vector in your little shared memory, all you're placing there with placement-new is a bunch of housekeeping data and the pointer to the actual data. After all, `sizeof` is a compile-time constant, are you not at all curious why it works on something as dynamic as `vector`?

As to the pointer, pointers are only valid in the address space of an application, it's not even portable across different applications on the same machine. This solution isn't viable for IPC, you'll have to devise a different one.

Comment: But OP specified a custom allocator (`CustomAllocator<char>`) for their vector. There should be allocator implementations that do OP wants, i.e. allocate the vector's buffer in shared memory. That's why `std::vector<T>` has a `pointer` typedef that's not necessarily `T*` but could be a 'fancy pointer' that handles shared memory. I guess however that the issue will be in OP's allocator implementation.

Comment: You're missing the point: no matter where the pointer is pointing to, even in the shared memory, the pointer value itself only makes sense for the application that created it. Each application on each machine gets their own virtual address space. It's how 32-bit applications can each get their own 2-4GB of virtual address space when you have more RAM than that.

Comment: Yes, but if the 'pointer' itself only is the offset from the base of the shared memory region, then each process could hold that base pointer (that's unique to each process) in some 'global' variable and when dereferencing the 'fancy pointer' it could construct an actual pointer from the global base pointer with the offset stored in the allocators fancy pointer. I didn't consider the global state though, so I don't know how desireable that solution would be admittedly.

Comment: It isn't a fancy pointer, it's the base `vector` implementation, which uses raw pointers, no matter how you allocate them (your custom allocator). And raw pointers are only valid for your own process on your own machine.

Comment: To be absolutely clear here: nothing stops you from writing a `vector`-like container that can work in IPC across shared memory, but the standard `vector` will never work like that.

Comment: I might have to read it up, but I'm pretty sure that the C++ allocator model was designed to make this case work by _only supplying a custom allocator_, without rewriting `std::vector`. Also at least in libc++, `std::vector`'s member variables begin, end and capacity are of type `std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::pointer`, not `T*`, which I'm pretty sure is the required behaviour. In the `data()` method it calls `std::to_address(__begin_)`, so the custom pointer type could be configured to convert the offset to an actual pointer here. I was suspecting that OP's `CustomAllocator` did just that.

Comment: Unfortunately it's hard to say anything about the code without knowing the implementation or at least specification of `CustomAllocator`.